# How to check if a comma was used in an input tag?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a few input tags, and my ajax script converts all values into a string separated by commas before sending it to the php script. Now if someone uses a comma in the input tags, then it breaks my read method, as values get broken. The tags aren't meant for text, and so there is no reason someone would use one, but just in case, how do i check if the user used a comma, using jquery.

Ideally, i would want:

```
$('element').keyup(function(event) {
      if(){//previous value was a comma
        alert('Commas not allowed!!');
        //Code to delete the comma
      }
    });
```

Thanks.

Comment: while key up you can check for comma presence in key down check for e.which

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use indexOf on the value of current input value.

```
 if(this.value.indexOf(',') !== -1)
 {
    //comma in input is not allowed
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like this. Store the previously pressed button and compare whether it was a comma or not. Then I will remove the second comma if present:

```
var previousKey = null;
$('input').keydown(function (event) {
    if (event.keyCode === 188 && previousKey === 188) {
        $val = $(this).val();
        $(this).val($val.substring(0,$val.length-1));
    }
    previousKey = event.keyCode;
});
```

Here's a demo:
http://jsfiddle.net/s1tqbopn/1/

*Suggestion*: why don't you use some of the already tested jQuery plugins for tag inputs. Such as the results from [this page](https://www.google.bg/search?q=jquery%20tag%20plugin&oq=jquery%20tag%20plugin&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.2156j0j9&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=93&ie=UTF-8).

Comment: Your code tries to do more than what i need. But it does teach me something. Thanks.